Burette waiting time
On the burette, the "EX" indicates that the burette is a "to deliver" type. The "+30 s" is the waiting time. I want to ask specifically with this waiting time.
(1) This is the time for a particular attempt of taking a desired volume. For example, I take just 5 mL, do I have to wait 30 seconds?
(2) This is the time for only the total volume taken from the burette from 0 to 25 mL.
In my opinion, I think that the (1) is correct, and regardless of how fast we dispense the burette, the time should be 30 seconds. Is that right?
